# is it possible to configure Delta Imports in Solr without making any change to Database Schema?

Tags: search, solr

I want to use solr indexing and want to have Delta Imports configured, for Delta Imports I need to change the Database schema to add the last modified datetime stamp which i dont want to do,

is it possible to configure Delta Imports in Solr without making any change to Database Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to leave you tables unchanged, you could create a View and add the necessary columns to keep track of what has been changed there, leaving your tables unchanged.

Comment: thats probably one of the way i can do it. just want to confirm i have got it right, i will create a view with an additional column lastmodifieddatetime. whenever a row is changed i need to store that datetime in this column but view does not contain any data, Will this view be created to have data as well?

Comment: you could create an additional table to keep that data, and join it in the view, this way the original table is untouched

Comment: have you ever used DataImportScheduler? can that be used for delta imports without changing the schema?